# Significato di "licitte"

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> «Cosa credi? Quando so d’averlo sotto il letto, non mi serve mica. Ma se non ce l’ho sono capace di dovermi alzare anche tre o quattro volte. Il **licitte** è in fondo alla camerata, e nel corridoio c’è uno spiffero continuo».

A dire queste parole è la nonna dell'autore quando si trova ricoverata in ospizio.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "licitte" in questo brano? Ho cercato questa parola in parecchi dizionari, ma non l'ho trovata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il [**licitte**](https://www.toctocfirenze.it/parole-fiorentine-13-sfavato-licitte-palletico/) è un termine dialettale fiorentino che indica il gabinetto.

> Il lìcitte, o lìcet, altro non è che il gabinetto, il luogo di
>   decenza. Il tono popolare ha fatto proprio un nobile derivato del
>   latino (da licēre essere permesso) per significare con massima
>   discrezione un luogo che si aveva pudore anche solo a nominare. In
>   altri termini, il licitte è il solo luogo, nominato in lingua aulica,
>   in cui sono permesse certe cose; ma non solo. Questa parola segna un
>   retaggio di grazia profonda e rétro, cifra di rispetto per chi ci
>   ascolta. Dichiarare che si deve andare al pisciatoio non nobilita
>   nessuno; mandare al licitte qualcuno, invece, è da signori.

Trovi in Treccani la corrispondente [**licet**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/licet/):

> licet v. lat. [propr. indicativo presente del verbo licere, che
>   significa «è permesso»], usato in ital. come s. m. – Espressione usata
>   nel passato, oggi raramente, per indicare la latrina, spec. in scuole
>   e collegi (dalla domanda *licet?*, che anticamente lo scolaro rivolgeva
>   al maestro quando aveva bisogno di uscire): *andare al licet*.